# write.csv inflates size of file

Tags: r

Here's a .csv file of federal budget data, 1.8 MB large. It's in wide format and has about 4,500 rows.

https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BUDGET-2019-DB/csv/BUDGET-2019-DB-1.csv

I've tidied (gathered) the data and added a few columns. My new dataset is 218,064 rows. I exported the data using write.csv. It is now 73 MB. Huge!

https://github.com/ctmann/Federal.Budget/blob/master/Data/Processed/omb.budget.authority.FY2019_Updated.2018-12-21.1942.csv

Is this increase in size normal? Are there any ways to mitigate such a large increase (1.8MB to 73MB)?

Comment: 218k rows is way more than 4k, so it's not that surprising. Wide forms are sometimes very memory efficient—even though they're a pain to operate on—because they don't repeat grouping values. That said 200k rows is still not *that* big, so one solution (depending on your application) is to save in a binary format instead of plaintext so the data can be compressed.

Comment: Also consider options other than CSV. How will the file be used next? Do you need human readability? You could compress, you can save it as an `Rds`. If you make categorical variables `factor`s then something like `feather` may be smaller as well (not positive about that).

Comment: Saving your data in `.ODS` format brings the size down to 15 MB. On Linux, you could use `library( gnumeric )` to move between the two formats.

Comment: These are all VERY helpful comments. 1) Tidy format takes up more space (@alistaire); 2) try using factors (@Gregor), and 3) Look for alternative formats to .csv, like .ods (open document spreadsheet), .rds or feather (@Gregor, @vaettchen). The finished file will be used in Excel by most people.

Comment: Can you open it using something like Notepad++?  That will show all tabs, end-of-line characters, and actually all possible characters that could be contributing to the bloat.  Also, you may have blank rows in between rows of data, or maybe even a bunch of blank rows at the end of the file.